# C++ Speed of camera is not what expected

Tags: c++, performance, graphics, camera

So right now in c++ i have a first person camera, where the controls are ok, and the camera moves fine. But my only problem is the speed of the camera isn't what expected, let me explain:

(3D Scenes)

10 Objects -> Camera speed is fast

1000 Object -> SLOW camera speed

---

So basically what i do is to multiple with time like this:

Newpos += Speed * DeltaTime;

But still when my program has loads to do, the camera speed decreases a lot! So what is happening here, what am I doing wrong?

Time code(the results seem fine, and they are in seconds):

```
double DeltaTime::milliseconds_now() 
{
    static LARGE_INTEGER s_frequency;
    static BOOL s_use_qpc = QueryPerformanceFrequency(&s_frequency);
    if (s_use_qpc) {
        LARGE_INTEGER now;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&now);
        return (1000LL * now.QuadPart) / s_frequency.QuadPart;
    } else {
        return GetTickCount();
    }
}

void DeltaTime::OnStart()
{
    //ticks = (float)GetTickCount();
    QueryPerformanceFrequency( &m_liPerformanceFrequency);
}

float DeltaTime::GetDelta()
{
    return ((float)dTime/(float)1000000.0f);
}

void DeltaTime::OnFinish()
{
    if (timeFirst)
    {
        //ticks = 0;
        dTime = 0;
        timeFirst = false;
        return;
    }

    //ticks = ((float)ticks = (float)GetTickCount() - (float)ticks);
    QueryPerformanceCounter( &liPerformanceCount);
    dTime = double(liPerformanceCount.QuadPart)/double(m_liPerformanceFrequency.QuadPart);
}
```

Frames:

```
void OnFrame(...)
{
 ...
 timeHandler.OnFinish();
 timeHandler.OnStart();
 ...
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I was calling the on start function twice, but now anyway the system is modified.